# create new instances or use public static methods?

Tags: c#, static, instance, public

Which one is the better way for a asp.net application in which i need to call methods from multiple pages? Or is there a third even better possibility?

Comment: It depends on what methods will be used for. Can you give more info?

Comment: One for a web request and another one to handle the response..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either works just fine. Another alternative is to build your own base class for pages, and put the common functionality there. With that approach, you can make the methods virtual and allow concrete classes to override functionality where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can also inherit all the pages from a common base page. But I would opt for the public static method if you do not need access to Page class members. Depends on what you actually want to achieve